# Cauchy sequence in a discrete space

Tags: general-topology, cauchy-sequences

how to prove that any Cauchy sequence in a discrete space  is stationary

Let $(x_n)$ be a cauchy sequence then $$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists n_0\in \mathbb{N},\forall p,q \geq n_0\Rightarrow \begin{cases} 1\leq \varepsilon, x_p\neq x_q\\ 0\leq \varepsilon,x_p=x_q\end{cases}$$

how to continue?

thank you

Comment: Terminology: The term "discrete space"  means every subset is open, but does not automatically mean that it has a metric  $d$ satisfying $d(x,y)=1$ whenever $x\ne y.$  That $d$ is called "the discrete metric" but other metrics may generate the discrete topology. For example  $\{1/n: n\in \Bbb N\}$ is a discrete subspace of $\Bbb R$ and its topology is generated by the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|.$

Answer (score 1):

The function $d:\mathbb N\times \mathbb N\rightarrow[0,+\infty)$ defined as $d(m,n)=\left|\displaystyle\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}\right|$ is a metric, which induces discrete topology on $\mathbb N$. The sequence $(n,n\in\mathbb N)$ is a Cauchy sequence in the space $(\mathbb N,d)$, and this sequence is not stationary.